# Visual Studio gitignore and mdf, ldf files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, gitignore

I have a database project that generates these files and added to gitignore. However they don't seem to be getting ignored and I need to revert them before commiting, quite annoying. The files are still locked by VS, is this a problem?

```
#
# Windows and Mac OS X Temp Cache Files
#
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

#
#Visual Studio files
#
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.dbmdl
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.Database.dbmdl
ipch/
obj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/

#
#Tooling
#
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*

#
#Project files
#
[Bb]uild/

#
#Subversion files
#
.svn

#
# Microsoft Office Temp Files
#
~$*

#
# YoureOnTime specific files
#
YoureOnTime.Database.dbmdl


# End of File
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I need to revert them before commiting

indicates that they are already versioned and were entered into `.gitignore` **after** they were added using `git add`.

Two possible solutions:

1. temporarily take them out of your `.gitignore`, then
   `git rm --cached -- *.mdf` and
   `git rm --cached -- *.ldf`.
   This will remove the files from the index while [keeping them on disk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rm). When done,
   `git commit -m "removing crap from repo"` and restore your `.gitignore`.
2. If you don't want to play around with your `.gitignore`, you could use [`update-index`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-update-index):
   `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- *.mdf` and
   `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- *.ldf`.
   This will force git to see the files as unchanged even if they were.